# Is it useful to multithread sql queries to fetch data from a large DB

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

I am writing my bachelor thesis on a project with a massive database that tracks around 8000 animals, three times a second. After a few months, we now have approx 127 million entries and each row includes a column with an array with 1000-3000 entries that has the coordinates for every animal that was tracked in that square that moment. All that lays in a sql database that now easily exceeds 2 TB in size.

To export the data and analyse the moving patterns of the animals, they did it online over PHPMyAdmin as a csv export that would take hours to be finished and break down about everytime.
I wrote them a python (they wanted me to use python) script with mysql-connector-python that will fetch the data for them automatically. The problem is, since the database is so massive, one query can take up minutes or technically even hours to complete. (downloading a day of tracking data would be 3*60*60*24 entries)
The moment anything goes wrong (connection fails, computer is overloaded etc) the whole query is closed and it has to start all over again cause its not cached anywhere.

---

I then rewrote the whole thing as a class that will fetch the data by using smaller multithreaded queries.

- I start about 5-7 Threads that each take a connection out of a connection pool, make the query, write it in a csv file successively and put the connection back in the pool once done with the query.
- My solution works perfectly, the queries are about 5-6 times faster, depending on the amount of threads I use and the size of the chunks that I download. The data gets written into the file and when the connection breaks or anything happens, the csvfile still holds all the data that has been downloaded up to that point.
- But on looking at solutions how to improve my method, I can find absolutely nothing about a similar approach and no-one seems to do it that way for large datasets.

---

- What am I missing? Why does it seem like everyone is using a single-query approach to fetch their massive datasets, instead of splitting it into threads and avoiding these annoying issues with connection breaks and whatnot?
- Is my solution even usable and good in a commercial environment or are there things that I just dont see right now, that would make my approach useless or even way worse?
- Or maybe it is a matter of the programming language and if I had used C# to do the same thing it wouldve been faster anyways?

EDIT:
To clear some things up, I am not responsible for the database. While I can tinker with it since I also have admin rights, someone else that (hopefully) actually knows what he is doing, has set it up and writes the data. My Job is only to **fetch** it as simple and effective as possible. And since exporting from PHPMyAdmin is too slow and so is a single query on python for 100k rows (i do it using `pd.read_sql`) I switched to multithreading. So my question is only related to `SELECT`ing the data effectively, not to change the DB.

I hope this is not becoming too long of a question...

Comment: What are you doing with the data? If you can move analysis from python to SQL, and leverage mysql indexes, it will be faster.

Comment: If you want performance out of your SQL to CSV pipe, you definitely shouldn't be using Pandas (`pd.read_sql()`) in-between. Secondly, the schema (`timestamp, positions` if I understand correctly) sounds _very_ suboptimal to query.

Comment: Should I `execute` the query directly? What is the most effecient way for that?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in a database of that size.  We need to do the processing fast enough so that it never gets behind.  (Once it lags, it will keel over, as you see.)

- Ingestion.  It sounds like a single client is receiving 8000 lat/lng values every 3 seconds, then `INSERTing` a single, quite wide row.  Is that correct?
- When you "process" the data, are you looking at each of the 8000 animals?  Or looking at a selected animal?  Fetching one out of a lat/lng from a wide row is messy and slow.
- If the primary way things are SELECTed is one animal at a time, then your matrix needs to be transposed.  That will make selecting all the data for one animal much faster, and we can mostly avoid the impact that Inserting and Selecting have on each other.
- Are you inserting while you are reading?
- What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  You must plan carefully with the 2TB versus the much smaller RAM size.  Depending on the queries, you may be terribly I/O-bound and maybe the data structure can be changed to avoid that.
- "...csv file and put it back..." -- Huh?  Are you deleting data, then re-inserting it?  That sees 'wrong'.  And very inefficient.
- Do minimize the size of every column in the table.  How big is the range for the animals?  Your backyard?  The Pacific Ocean?  How much precision is needed in the location?  Meters for whales; millimeters for ants.  Maybe the coordinates can be scaled to a pair of `SMALLINTs` (2 bytes, 16-bit precision) or `MEDIUMINTs` (3 bytes each)?

I haven't dwelled on threading; I would like to wait until the rest of the issues are ironed out.  Threads interfere with each other to some extent.

I find this topic interesting.  Let's continue the discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated my question. My job is related to fetch the data and put it in a csv file

Comment: I can't even address the narrow question without knowing the schema (`CREATE TABLE`) and the query (`SELECT`).